# Difference between bash sleep and sleep in C program

Tags: c, bash

From: [http://www.utdallas.edu/~kcooper/teaching/5375/fall08/Tutorial8/tutorial8.htm](http://www.utdallas.edu/%7Ekcooper/teaching/5375/fall08/Tutorial8/tutorial8.htm)

(Section "Difference between bash sleep and sleep in C program"):

> There is a major difference between how bash sleep command and sleep function of C program works. The sleep function of C programs is a simple function call. When called, it gives up the CPU to the operating system so that it can schedule other processes which need CPU. Then after the specified amount of seconds, the process which called sleep starts working again.
>
> The sleep command bash works differently. When this command is invoked, it creates a child process of itself. It runs for the specified amount of seconds and then exits back to the calling process.

1. Why does bash sleep so complicated? (Why does bash sleep is realized through the forking?)
2. Why bash sleep can't be like C sleep?

Comment: Maybe take it up with the authors of `bash` and not with us? There's simply no "sleep"-type builtin in the version of Bash you are using...

Comment: Just to restate it so it's perfectly clear, there is no "bash sleep". There is an external utility `/bin/sleep`.

Comment: The page you linked has at least a few errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does bash sleep so complicated? (Why does bash sleep is realized through the forking?

Because that's what bash does, it runs programs (which on unixes is done through fork()/exec() )  It so just happens that someone wrote a program, `/bin/sleep` which just sleeps for the specified amount of seconds.

> Why bash sleep can't be like C sleep?

It could, if someone implemented sleep as a built in command/function to bash, but no-one has yet, and likely the benefit is not worth it.

Answer (score 2):

I think that information is just misleading. If `sleep` is an external program (`/bin/sleep`) invoked by the shell, then all the extra work is invoking the external program; the sleep program itself just calls the sleep function. There's no reason a shell couldn't provide a builtin for the `sleep` command that just calls the `sleep` function without forking a new process; however, the benefits would be dubious at best. Since the standard `sleep` command will always sleep at least one second and the overhead of starting an external program is on the order of microseconds, I don't see any way it would help performance.

Comment: A [completely random link](http://dis.4chan.org/read/prog/1295544154) only very tangentially related.

Comment: `ksh93` and `mksh` have a `sleep` builtin, and most `sleep` implementations allow sleeping fractional seconds.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the order of magnitude difference between the launch time and run time of the `sleep` command.

Answer (score 1):

Because when executing external command you can replace the 'sleep' (default to `/bin/sleep`) with your own sleep e.g. in `$HOME/bin/sleep` - with a simple PATH change...

External commands = freedom.

As @nos already told: bash is doing for what is designed -> executing programs.

Answer (score 0):

Well bash is just meant to execute other programs or scripts. Think of sleep being invoked in background mode. Bash is supposed to execute the script and not understand and implement logic in it. Behavior is well justified.